# Why can't i do commands in root terminal on a new user? Kali linux

Tags: terminal, kali-linux

When I try to run a command like `Service`, it doesn't work. I need help.
I tried to run `Apt-get update` but it didn't fix this problem. The new user has standard permissions.

Comment: This is not how you use the site. You've [asked the same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570265/why-isnt-simple-commands-working-on-new-users-in-kali-linux) ans it was closed, and this one is not an improvement. You didn't answer to [the comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570265/why-isnt-simple-commands-working-on-new-users-in-kali-linux#comment1060682_570265) either. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/570265/edit) your original question and give all the details possible.

Comment: Read [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).

Comment: Why you do this to me i just want to be able to do commands in my computer!

Comment: @Sirana: We are more than happy to help but you can't open multiple duplicate questions.  Answer the question(s) and clarify your previous question and it will be reopened so that people can answer it.  Right now your questions are not clear enough to answer.

Comment: What do i need to do exactly?

Comment: @Sirana: Show the actual command you are using and the error message you are getting

Comment: @Sirana: [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/570265/edit) your last question to include the exact command you are running including the error messages that you are getting.

Comment: Ok, i did it, can you guys or girls make it online for the public to see?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that on most unix systems commands are case-sensitive. Running `service` or `apt-get update` is probably what you want.